# Alternative solution similar to Keras kfold for multi input multi output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have a flow past airfoil problem involving 3 inputs (AOA,x,y) and 3 outputs (u,v,p). It's working well when I use train_test_split.

Then, I wanted to try using Keras kFold to validate my overall prediction accuracy:

```
...
input_var = np.vstack((AOA, x, y)).T
output_var = np.vstack((u,v,p)).T

# define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed_value)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(input_var, output_var):

    # create model
...
```

However I got the error:

```
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous-multioutput' instead.
```

So is there some error? Or multi input output is not supported at all.

I am thinking of an alternative solution of looping manually and using train_test_split with a different random state each time, so as to select a different test data every time. Then computer the overall mean MSE.

Is this logical? Will I achieve the same effect as kFold?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a classification or regression problem? BTW, `StratifiedKFold` is a scikit-learn module, not a Keras one.

Comment: I just read that since my problem is a regression one, I should be using KerasRegressor.

Comment: Well, that's what I have asked since yesterday... Keep in mind that the expected SO practice is to be around for at least ~ 30 mins since asking, in order to answer to classification requests from people trying to help - opening a question just before leaving office or going to bed is not recommended. Also be advised that `StratifiedKFold` is not applicable for regression.